# Should chrome on ipad dispatch a resize event when the keyboard displays?

Tags: javascript, ipad, google-chrome, window-resize

Chrome on ipad is dispatching a resize event on the window object any time the key board displays or hides, say for example when you touch and focus into a text box, or lose focus by tapping something else. The new view port height is the height of the screen minus the keyboard. When in portrait, this is not very tall at all.

My JavaScript app does some very screwed up things when this happens because it attempts to scale an image to fit the screen like "full screen" effect, and there is an input box laid on top of this which when focused it opens another layer on top to show some possibilities for auto complete. Then focusing on this text box makes the screen go haywire (scale down image drastically, reposition input box to correspond with new location, etc.) and eventually causes the input to lose focus, making the keyboard disappear causing resize again. So basically the screen has a seizure and the user cannot type or select anything in this widget.

I want to know not how to fix my bug, which I believe I know some ways to mitigate it, but what if anything does the specs say should happen here (if any specs actually exist) and if I can legitimately call this unwanted behavior (or perhaps even a bug) in chrome ipad.

Ipad safari does not do this, the window maintains a constant height as far as I can tell. So my bug only happens in ipad chrome but not ipad safari.